# Is there a way to hide the recording icon on the menu bar?

Tags: macos, mac, quicktime, recording, screen-recording

Using `Quick Time Player` or the one which shows up on `CMD+SHIFT+5` I get the following icon in the menu bar:

[image]

Is there a way to hide that? If not can you recommend another free software which I can use?

**EDIT**

I found that you can remove the entire menu bar, wondering if you could just hide the icon itself?

[image]

Comment: Why is the icon a problem? Do you want to record/screengrab just a part of the screen, without the menubar?

Comment: The icon is a problem because the interviewer might ask me "hey why are you recording this"?

Comment: Why would an interviewer be seeing *your* screen?

Comment: Because I'm sharing it.

Comment: You can record selections of the screen using QuickTime Player. Note that recording people without consent is unlawful in some places, and impolite in most.

Comment: I worked for a huge company which never disclosed to the interviewee that they are being recorded how unlawful is that? How do you think the world works? Even smaller sections of the screen will render the icon on the menu bar. Anyways, I think I ll stick to the menu bar hiding technique.